HTTP Status 404 – Not Found tomcat after uploading jar files
I am sure I am doing something wrong but not sure of what.
I have an environment with one tomcat version 10 that uses openlogic jdk version 11. when I put war files inside the webapp and stop start the server, I see a lot of logs telling me that:
INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR Deploying web application archive [/opt/apache-tomcat-10.1.33/webapps/name-of.war] INFO [main] org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner.scanJars At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time. INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR Deployment of web application archive [/opt/apache-tomcat-10.1.33/webapps/name-of.war] has finished in [6,750] ms
for each one of this war there should be a context like ip:8080/name-of/ but I get HTTP Status 404 – Not Found first time using tomcat so surely i did something wrong somewhere.
